# should a module export a function named `exit()`?

Tags: python, module, naming-conventions

I'm currently working on a module that wraps a C-library (let's call it `foo`)

The C-library has its functions prefixed by `foo_` to avoid nameclashes with other libraries:

```
int foo_dothis(int x, int y);
void foo_dothat(struct foo_struct_*s);
```

In python, the `foo_` prefix makes little sense, as we have namespaces for that kind of things.

```
import foo
foo.dothis(42)
```

The C-library also has functions for initializing/deinitializing the entire library:

```
int foo_init(void);
void foo_exit(void);
```

Now i'm wondering whether I should strip the `foo_` prefix for those as well, in order to prevent confusion with the built-in `exit()`:

```
from foo import *
exit()
```

I guess it is OK, as

- being consistent is important
- `exit()` is easier to remember than `foo_exit()`
- `foo.exit()` is prettier than `foo.foo_exit()`
- people are generally discouraged to use `exit()` in production code (and should only use it in the interpreter)
- importing all symbols from a module asks for trouble anyhow

So what is the common approach to that (best-practice,...)

Answer (score 0):

Since the role of `foo_exit()` is to uninitialise the library, and this is kind of the inverse of `foo_init()`, you could simply use name `foo.uninit()` for the Python function. This will avoid name clashes and confusion with the builtin `exit()`, and its purpose should be obvious to users of the module.